# Writing a VHDL Module

Tags: fpga, vhdl

I am trying to get through this section of a course: http://hamsterworks.co.nz/mediawiki/index.php/Module_9

I am trying to write the 30 bit counter module (Project 9.1 on the page). I have the counter wrote in a normal .vhd file from the previous sections in that course. Here is the code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

entity Clock_Signals is
    Port (  switches : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
                buttons     : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
                LEDs     : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
                clk      : in STD_LOGIC
         );
end Clock_Signals;

architecture Behavioral of Clock_Signals is
    signal counter : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(29 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal incHighNext : STD_LOGIC := '0';

    signal buttonsPrev : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0) := (others => '0');
begin
    LEDs <= counter(29 downto 22);

    count: process(clk)
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            -- Allows for a step through
            --if (buttons(0) = '1') and (buttonsPrev(0) = '0') then
                --counter <= counter+1;
            --end if;

            counter(29 downto 15) <= counter(29 downto 15)+incHighNext;

            if counter(14 downto 0) = "111111111111110" then
                incHighNext <= '1';
            else
                incHighNext <= '0';
            end if;

            counter(14 downto 0) <= counter(14 downto 0)+1;

            -- Update state
            buttonsPrev <= buttons;
        end if;
    end process;

end Behavioral;
```

But when I make a module, I can't figure out how to translate it over. Here is my current module:

```
module mymodule(
    input [3:0] clk,
     input [3:0] enable,
    output [3:0] count
    );

endmodule
```

Comment: It looks like you're slipping into Verilog, rather than VHDL. Pay closer attention to the syntax templates provided in the lesson.

Comment: @DaveTweed That module code is what was generated after created a new Source VHDL Module just like the instructions. I am not sure how I am supposed to translate the code from 6.1 into a module. If I am missing the point then please show me a example.

Comment: Whatever tool you are using, it did not create a new VHDL module. It created a new Verilog module. If you're tool doesn't provide good templates for you, you need to use a different tool, or simply copy templates from a more reliable source.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you accidentally clicked "Verilog Module" instead of "VHDL Module":

[image]

The code generated should look something like this:

```
   COMPONENT mymodule
   PORT(
      clk    : IN std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
      enable : IN std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);   
      output : OUT std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)
   );
   END COMPONENT;
```

Delete the accidental Verilog Module and try again paying close attention to which Source Type you choose.